# R: readr: is it possible to read HTML tables using this package

Tags: r, readr

I want to know if we can reach html tables using readr package with the url of the page where html table is published. For example, I want to import table on the  [page](http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/stats/byteam?group=Offense&cat=Total&conference=NFL&year=season_2010&sort=530&old_category=Total&old_group=Offense) to be loaded into R.

Comment: If you're not leaving Hadleyland, you want rvest.  But `XML::readHTMLTable()` will read that baby like a chizamp.

Comment: Did you read [the description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html)? *"Read flat/tabular text files from disk (or a connection)."*

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what a 'chizamp' might be, but Scriven is correct, albeit with a bit of extra noodling needed to figure out which of the multiple tables returned by `XML::readHTMLTables` might be the one you wanted:

```
> library(XML)
> help(pack=XML)
> sports <- readHTMLTable("http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/stats/byteam?group=Offense&cat=Total&conference=NFL&year=season_2010&sort=530&old_category=Total&old_group=Offense")
> str(sports[[1]])
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 1 level "": 1
 $ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "Search SportsSearch Web": 1
> str(sports[[2]])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ : Factor w/ 2 levels "","Sortable Stats": 2 1
> length(sports)
[1] 8
> str(sports[[8]])
 NULL
# top of str() on the seventh item in that list
str(sports[[7]])
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  28 variables:
 $ Team     : Factor w/ 32 levels "Arizona Cardinals",..: 19 26 24 14 2 23 21 9 13 12 ...
 $          : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ G        : Factor w/ 1 level "16": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $          : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pts/G    : Factor w/ 28 levels "12.3","16.9",..: 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 22 21 20 ...
```

Comment: Can go straight to the seventh table with `which = 7`

Comment: Yes, but only if you know that it will be the seventh.